Get Parquet column names as values via T-SQL and OPENROWSET
I have a Parquet data lake stored in Azure Data Lake Gen2. I am using Synapse to perform serverless SQL queries on this data lake - and I then visualize this via Grafana, using Microsoft SQL Server as the data source. I am using OPENROWSET rather than creating External Tables.
My Parquet files are structured as below:
device/message/yyyy/mm/dd/xyz.parquet

In Grafana, I wish to create 'Variable' drop downs for enabling users to dynamically select devices, messages and columns within those messages.
I am struggling to create a single query that extracts the column names as values. I need this in order to create a 'column' variable dropdown. I have tried with below query:
SELECT TOP 1
    * 
FROM 
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK '3BA199E2/CAN2_gnssimu/*/*/*/*',
        DATA_SOURCE = 'ParquetDataLake',
        FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
    ) AS r
WHERE 
    CONCAT(r.filepath(1), '-', r.filepath(2), '-', r.filepath(3)) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, $__timeFrom()) AND CONVERT(date, $__timeTo())
    AND
    $__timeFilter(t)

This works to some extent as it returns the columns of a selected device/message folder, but it also returns the 1st row. In Grafana, the implication is that the Variable dropdown contains the 1st row values, rather than the column values.
I am looking for a modified query that will instead return the column names as the end result.

Sounds like you're working with wrong tools for the task.
For your general question though, if you want to get columns from some "unknown" source, you can use the following technique:
select [key]
from openjson((
    SELECT  TOP 1   * 
    FROM    OPENQUERY([localhost], 'select top 1 * from sys.objects')
    for json path), '$[0]')

I'm using OPENQUERY here, but you can use your OPENROWSET thing in same way.
You create a json from first row of your select, which you then unwrap by using OPENJSON against the first array row. This generate a list of keys, which you can use as column names.
Edit:
An alternative method:
select name
from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'
    SELECT  TOP 1   * 
    FROM    OPENQUERY([localhost], ''select top 1 * from sys.objects'')', null, 0)

Example output:



key




name


object_id


schema_id


parent_object_id


type


type_desc


create_date


modify_date


is_ms_shipped


is_published


is_schema_published




I tried this: SELECT [key]  FROM OPENJSON((     SELECT TOP 1 *      FROM          OPENROWSET(             BULK '3BA199E2/CAN2_gnssimu/*/*/*/*',             DATA_SOURCE = 'ParquetDataLake',             FORMAT = 'PARQUET'         ) AS r     WHERE          CONCAT(r.filepath(1), '-', r.filepath(2), '-', r.filepath(3)) BETWEEN CONVERT(date, $__timeFrom()) AND CONVERT(date, $__timeTo())         AND        $__timeFilter(t)    FOR JSON PATH), '$[0]') - but in this case I get a warning: The query references an object that is not supported in distributed processing mode.

Warning or error? Can you put the data into a temporary table and then do the JSON thing?

I get an error and the query does not run. The queries need to run within Grafana, where I am only able to execute single-query statements to my knowledge. So if a Table was to be created temporarily, it would have to be done somehow in a single query - not sure if that is doable

Oh ok, then it won't work :/ I added an alternative method, maybe that one will work? Although i doubt it

Thanks, I tried the other suggestion, but I get this: DMV (Dynamic Management View) 'dm_exec_describe_first_result_set' is not supported.

Yeah, synapse doesn't support anything interesting :) Ok, i guess i'm out of ideas. Can delete this answer if you want
